# Sightly not recognizing html

Tags: aem, sightly

I have method which is returning html as a string value. I thought while displaying it will show me string in bold on browser but its showing me the string as is on browser.

```
public String getHtml() {
        return "<b>kunal</b>";
    }

<sly data-sly-use.item="demo.html.DemoHtml">
    ${item.html}
</sly>
```

Output:

```
<b>kunal</b>
```

Any workaround on this?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

HTL/Sightly includes XSS protection and will escape your string by default unless you explicitly tell it contains HTML (see https://github.com/Adobe-Marketing-Cloud/htl-spec/blob/master/SPECIFICATION.md#121-display-context):

```
${item.html @ context='html'}
```